# Android, How to embed AdMob into WebView (Web Integration) ?

Tags: android, webview, integration, admob

I'm trying to integrate an admob banner into my Android application. I have no problem with activities and I see adds in my activities. However, I have problem with WebView. I don't know how should I embed Java Script code into WebView. 
I saw http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android but I couldn't solve my problem.
My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var admob_vars = {
 pubid: 'MY_ID', // publisher id
 bgcolor: '0000FF', // background color (hex)
 text: 'ff8c00', // font-color (hex)
 test: true // test mode, set to false to receive live ads
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js"></script>
```

I want to show my adds at the top of the screen, therefore I have written something like following code in mt html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>People</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var admob_vars = {
 pubid: 'MY_ID', // publisher id
 bgcolor: '0000FF', // background color (hex)
 text: 'ff8c00', // font-color (hex)
 test: false // test mode, set to false to receive live ads
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is my problem?

Comment: So, you've described what you want but not what the problem is.  Should we assume that nothing is displayed?  What have you tried?  Can you replace the AdMob javascript with your own javascript and prove that that works?  Have you followed AdMob's FAQ? http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android#FAQ

Comment: Thanks dear Klox. The problem is advertise did not show. I want to know is my procedure correct? Thx